# Error : Database is locked in sqlite3

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlite, timeout

I'm working on a python script where I'm connecting database of multiple server and executing the same query on all.
Now, the issue is the database on some servers are locked, so need to understand how to unlock the same or if we can use timeout to skip few of the servers and run the query uninterrupted on remaining servers.

Comment: put it in a `try catch` so it skips the locked databases?

Comment: Improve your question using the guidelines explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To unlock, just kill the other processes that are accessing these databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3.connect()` has a [timeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) parameter (in seconds).

But I recommend to change database to a client-server solution. SQLite is ok to handle large database for single program, but it's not very good at handling concurrent access from multiple programs. MySQL or Postgres will suite you much better.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Yes, i used the timeout parameter, but it is not working. Is there any other way out so that I can unlock the database or may be skip the same.